# Can't display leftComponentIcon in NavigationBar

Tags: react-native

I add react-native-navigation-bar to my project. I want to display the left icon as a sidebar icon. I try this code but  nothing is displayed :

```
   <NavigationBar
    title={'New Tech'}
    height={80}
    titleColor={'#fff'}
    leftComponent={<Icon name="rocket"/> }
    />
```

ps: am installing react-native-vector-icons and import it by :

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

Any help isappreciated.

Comment: have you follow the configuration ? like type this one `react-native link`

Comment: i just install  NavigationBar .

Comment: i mean, you use `react-native-vector-icons` right ? have you try in another component ? is the icon show or not ?

Comment: yeess , it works fine. I test it with another component

Comment: have you try to change `leftComponent` to `leftButtonIcon` ?

Comment: it depends on your Navigation Version, but it is either called `left` or `headerLeft` (newer versions is the later)

Comment: i change it nothing is changed :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Navigation Version, but it is either called `left` or `headerLeft` (newer versions is the later):

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `whatever`,
    headerLeft: <Button title="" onPress={() => {/*do something*/}} />,
});
```

Comment: i think this related to stacknavigation?